# Grep numbers between colon and comma

Tags: perl, bash, sed, awk, grep

I want to grep all results which contain over 70 percent of usage

Example of output:

```
{"ipaddr":"1.1.1.1","hostname":"host1.test.com","percentage":69,"dir":"/root"},
{"ipaddr":"1.1.1.1","hostname":"host1.test.com","percentage":79,"dir":"/oracle"},
{"ipaddr":"1.1.1.1","hostname":"host1.test.com","percentage":1,"dir":"/oradump"},
{"ipaddr":"1.1.1.1","hostname":"host1.test.com","percentage":90,"dir":"/archive"},
```

Expected View after the grep:

```
{"ipaddr":"1.1.1.1","hostname":"host1.test.com","percentage":79,"dir":"/oracle"},
{"ipaddr":"1.1.1.1","hostname":"host1.test.com","percentage":90,"dir":"/archive"},
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Awk is more suited here:

```
$ awk -F'[:,]' '$6>70' file
{"ipaddr":"1.1.1.1","hostname":"host1.test.com","percentage":79,"dir":"/oracle"},
{"ipaddr":"1.1.1.1","hostname":"host1.test.com","percentage":90,"dir":"/archive"},
```

Comment: +1 for suggesting the right tool for this job. This is tailor made for awk

Answer (score 3):

Or with Perl:

```
$ perl -ne'print if /"percentage":([0-9]+),/ and $1 > 70'
```

(no pesky seperator counting needed)

Answer (score 3):

```
perl -F'[:,]' -ane 'print if $F[5]>70' file
```

Answer (score 0):

### GNU sed

```
sed -n '/:[0]\?70,/d;/:[0-1]\?[7-9][0-9],/p' file
```